# Obj-C, how to stop NSURLConnection behind NSData?

Tags: objective-c

how can I stop NSURLConnection behind NSURLConnection ?

code:

```
 NSData *sendreq = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlreq returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *responseStr =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[sendreq bytes] length:[sendreq length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I use the NSData to store the response from my server, but in this way I cant use "[sendreq cancel]"
so if the NSURLConnection is making a long connection and the user is go to anther VC I want to stop the NSURLConnection, so how can I do it ?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I edited the question with more details

Comment: Don't use `sendSynchronousRequest`. Don't use `initWithBytes`, use `initWithData`.

Comment: OK, and how can I stop the NSConnection ??

Comment: Look at the `NSURLConnection` documentation, the `cancel` method should jump out at you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to cancel your request, do not use `sendSynchronousRequest`, but instead use the asynchronous, delegate-based rendition `NSURLConnection`. (Frankly, you should avoid using synchronous requests, from the main thread at least, for a variety of reasons.) If you use the delegate-based rendition, you can then call `NSURLConnection` method `cancel` when needed.

So, define properties to hold the data and connection reference:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSURLConnection *connection;
```

Then start the connection:

```
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlreq delegate:self];
self.connection = connection;
```

You obviously have to implement the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // you can use `responseStr` here

    // now that we're done with `responseData`, we might want to release it

    self.responseData = nil;
}
```

You want to detect/handle errors, too, with the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // do whatever you want when error occurs
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}
```

If you need to cancel it, it's

```
[self.connection cancel];
```

---

You could also use AFNetworking, which uses delegate-based `NSURLConnection`, but keeps you out of the weeds of the implementation.

You can also use the newer `NSURLSession` which offers block-based renditions that are still can be cancelled. But that depends upon what OS versions you're trying to support.